# Pass google script variable/array to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm building a web app that is google's chart Timeline. I have a script that returns me the correct array from google sheets. I want to pass this result to HTML in a specific place. I'm using google app scripts.

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('timeline3').evaluate();


}

function useDataRange() {
  
var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getRange(3, 7, rows.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

test = test.slice(0,rows.getLastRow()-2);
JSON.stringify(test);
Logger.log(test);
return test;

}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);

      function getData(){

        return google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).useDataRange();
        
      }
      function drawChart(arrayFromSheets) {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline-tooltip');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });        
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'dummy bar label' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows(arrayFromSheets);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
    </script>
    <div id="timeline-tooltip" style="height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to populate dataTable.addRows() with my array. I've looked through google's documentation and this should work. I just don't get it. Please help

Here is an example of array I get returned from useDataRange function:

```
[['Lady Gita' ,null , 'June 19 -26' , '#176BEF', new Date(2021, 6, 19) , new Date(2021, 6, 26)], ['Lady Gita' ,null , 'Jun 27 - Jul 11' , '#FF3E30', new Date(2021, 6, 27) , new Date(2021, 7, 11)]]
```

Searching in console I get this:
[Console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdTqq.png)

Comment: I've replicated your script and the issue could be due to the date in the array. The date in the array when passed will be in this format: "Thu Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-15:56 1789". This is just purely based on my observations, but it looks like the dataTable will fail to identify the date on the array, thus the chart creation. All sample articles/resources from Google Charts only show the use of JavaScript Date class like "new Date(1789, 3, 30)" when adding a date value on the dataTable & it looks this is not possible (at least to Google Chart) given there are no existing guide online.

Comment: An alternative option that you can try is the guide from "Creating a Chart from a Separate Spreadsheet" at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#creating-a-chart-from-a-separate-spreadsheet.

Comment: yes, use the Query class as noted above...

Comment: Hey Irvin and WhiteHate, thank you for you answers. I'll update you when I do it :)

Comment: Hey, I really suck at querries, have to take time to learn them. I updated my answer with working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays weren't being passed as arrays because I had a function inside them. They were all being passed as undefined. I had to change a bit my sheet but it works now. Also null was showing as BarLabel so I turned BarLabel off with options. It works great now!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);

      function getData(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).useDataRange();
      }

      function drawChart(data) {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline-tooltip');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President'});        
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'dummy bar label'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End'});
        
        var rows = [];

        //Loop through the data you loaded and push it to the rows array
       

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          var currentElement = data[i];
          var transformFirstDate = new Date(currentElement[4]);
          var transformSecondDate = new Date(currentElement[5]);

          rows.push([currentElement[0],currentElement[1],currentElement[2],currentElement[3],transformFirstDate,transformSecondDate]);
        }

        

        dataTable.addRows(rows);

        var options = {
        timeline: { showBarLabels: false }        
      };

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="timeline-tooltip" style="height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getRange(3, 7, rows.getLastRow()-2, 1).getValues();`  The third param is number of rows not last row

Comment: Hey Cooper. Thank you for your answer. I'm not having a problem with getting the correct array. My logger clearly shows the correct array and if I just paste it in HTML it works. I want to pass this array to HTML code in addRows();.

Comment: I assumed the html has already been rendered so you will have to request the array and have it returned to a withSuccessHandler

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the answer! I thought I already did request the array and return it (see function getData()). I opened console and it gives me this:

jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:295 Uncaught Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array

So it was not clear to me what happens when getData is executed so I put after that function closes alert(getData()); and it alerts: undefined